# Useful Unicode Characters for Islam.SE

Tags: discussion

I recently found out that there are unicode characters specific to Islam. I wanted to share them, so that we could use them on our answers and questions.

- ﷲ - Arabic word Allah (c.c) - HTML entity `&#65010;`
- ﷴ - Arabic word Muhammed (pbuh)- HTML entity `&#65012;`
- ﷺ - Arabic phrase "Peace be Upon him" - HTMl entity `&#65018;`
- ﷻ - Arabic phrase "may his glory be glorified" - HTML entity `&#65019;`
- ﷽ - Arabic phrase bismi-llāhi r-raḥmāni r-raḥīm - HTML entity `&#65021;`

For more Unicode arabic characters/phrases; see: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/arabic_presentation_forms_a/list.htm

Comment: A word of caution: Not everyone has fonts that support these characters.  My own system, for example, only displays the first one.